# Does intermittent fasting promote neurogenesis through the same mechanism as aerobic exercises?

Tags: neuroscience

I heard that intermittent fasting promote neurogenesis through the secretion of BDNF, I heard aerobic exercises does the same through BDNF. Now, I am wondering if there are other mechanisms through which aerobic exercises promote neurogenesis, but through which intermittent fasting doesn't.